# adding custom request to joomla menu item in XML

Tags: xml, model-view-controller, joomla

I'm trying to modify the XML file for hikashop in order to add an extra dropdown which allows me to select certain types and values which will later be parsed by a php file. It boils down to the fact that I want to add an extra request to the menu item and the only way I know of doing this is by adding a request field in the XML file.

Currently it does actually work, but only my custom field is displayed; the other one is lost. If i place the  tag inside the fieldset tag, the functionality does not work anymore.

Here is my xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
    <state>
        <name>Product page</name>
        <params addpath="/components/com_hikashop/params">
            <param name="product_id" type="selectproduct" default="0" label="Select a product" description="Select here the product to display for the current link" />
    </params>
</state>
<layout title="COM_HIKASHOP_PRODUCT_FORM_VIEW_DEFAULT_TITLE">
    <message></message>
</layout>
<fields name="params" addfieldpath="/components/com_hikashop/fields">
    <fieldset name="basic" label="Select a product">
        <field
            id="product_id"
            name="product_id"
            type="selectproduct"
            label="Select a product"
            description="Select here the product to display for the current link"
                            />


    </fieldset>


</fields>

<fields name="request">
    <fieldset name="request">
        <field
            name="viewType"
            type="list"
            label="Type of Product"
            description="Select the type of product to grab the correct template"
            default="2"
        >
            <option value="1">Brace</option>
            <option value="2">Shoe</option>
            <option value="3">misc</option>
        </field>
    </fieldset>

</fields>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml is incorrectly structured. All parameters should be inside `<fields>` tag, but there can be only one such tag, all parameters should be nested inside. So the fields part should be like this:

```
<fields name="params" addfieldpath="/components/com_hikashop/fields">
    <fieldset name="basic" label="Select a product">
        <field
            id="product_id"
            name="product_id"
            type="selectproduct"
            label="Select a product"
            description="Select here the product to display for the current link"
                            />
        <field
            name="viewType"
            type="list"
            label="Type of Product"
            description="Select the type of product to grab the correct template"
            default="2"
        >
            <option value="1">Brace</option>
            <option value="2">Shoe</option>
            <option value="3">misc</option>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</fields>
```

Comment: That's what I did to begin with, but then the request fieldset does not appear.. :(

Comment: @Ortix92 maybe because label was missing for fieldset? try again with the code I wrote

Comment: still nothing.. It doesn't appear in the source either (not surprised there)

Comment: @Ortix92 interesting. try with the latest edit, where everything is in the same fieldset